# How do I prevent a Builder template from escaping a URL in an attribute value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, url, escaping, builder

I have a Rails Builder template:

```
# in app/views/foos/index.xml.builder:
xml.Module do |mod|
  ...
  mod.Content :type => 'url',
          :href => foos_url(:bar => 'baz',
                            :yoo => 'hoo')
end
```

(It creates the XML for an OpenSocial Module file, but that's not important.)

The problem is that the rendered XML looks like this:

```
<Module>
  ...
  <Content type="url" href="http://myapp.com/foos?bar=baz&amp;amp;yoo=hoo"/>
</Module>
```

That URL suffix should be "`bar=baz&yoo=hoo`."  How do I keep Builder from escaping the amerpsand?

**Later**

Perhaps the URL suffix should be "`bar=baz&amp;yoo=hoo`" in the source for XML-validity rules, but certainly it shouldn't be *double*-escaped, should it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I'm late here - but for anyone coming in from google (like me) the trick is to add an :escape => false to the url_for - that way the url only gets escaped once.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's because XHTML requires the `&` to be escaped as `&amp;` (even in URLs) and the XML where you stores the URL requires this too, giving a double escapement (`&amp;amp;`) which will decode to `&amp;` in the URL, which is perfectly valid in HTML (and mandatory in XHTML).

For example, the following code is valid XHTML linking to `http://example.com/?a=b&c=d`:

```
<a href="http://example.com/?a=b&amp;c=d">link</a>
```

So my guess would be that `foos_url` returns you an url already containing a `&amp;`, then it is escaped again by your XML module.

Answer (score 0):

No it shouldn't, otherwise the generated XML file would be invalid, a correct parser will translate &amp; back to & when parsing the file.

Edit : nevermind, &amp; got translated into & in the first message.

Comment: But there are _two_ "amp"s there - the &amp; itself is escaped. That can't be right.